# Estimate the max length of chess game under WFCC?

Tags: mathematics, threefold-repetition, game-length

The World Federation of Chess Composition (WFCC) has a Codex that specifies how the FIDE Laws apply to chess problems.

Can you give a ballpark estimate of the length of the longest game possible under WFCC?

Relevant rules:

- Draw by triple repetition (3Rep) is automatic.
- Draw by 50 moves (50M) only applies to retrograde analysis problems, so doesn't apply to this challenge.
- Draws by quintuple repetition (5Rep) & 75 moves (75M) do not apply at all.